# Put button side by side in while loop in css

Tags: php, html, css

i am begineer on PHP but it can be so easy for experience people, but i am tried to learn. i just want to add button side by side, but according to my codes, which is one under the other.

```
while ($row_all = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
                {
                      echo '<form method="post">';
                        echo '<u>'.$row_all["product_name "].'</u>';
                        echo ' <button name="add_to_cart"  class="btn3" 
                        value='.$row_all['urun_adi'].' 
                        type="submit">'.$row_all["urun_adi"].'</button>';

                          echo '</form>';



                }
```

CSS code

```
  .btn3{
position: relative; 
top: 150px;
left: 1280px;   
width: 150px;
height: 100px;
border:5px solid white; 
color:yellow; 
font-weight:bold; 
font-family:Verdana; 
font-size:14px; 
background-color: green;
 }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean with "side by side"...

Comment: use "display: inline-block;" maybe?

Comment: It's not the button that is the issue here it is the form which is being repeated in the loop so you would need to style the form to probably `display:inline-block;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ! Create the form outside the while

```
echo '<form method="post">';

while ($row_all = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
                {

                        echo '<u>'.$row_all["product_name "].'</u>';
                        echo ' <button name="add_to_cart"  class="btn3" 
                        value='.$row_all['urun_adi'].' 
                        type="submit">'.$row_all["urun_adi"].'</button>';



                }
 echo '</form>';
```

Comment: thank you :) i have one more question, for example,after 5 buttons which is side by side,how can put botton row? @Rafael Castelani

Comment: css , border-bottom : 1px solid yellow !!